# windows 10 can't see network

Tags: windows-10, networking

in my network I have connected WD cloud, mac and windows computer. My mac can see my windows computer and WD cloud disk, but my windows computer cannot see my windows computer and wd cloud seems also notbe shared (I can see it, but if I open it, windows opens only website with login, on my mac I can see it as regular folder)

What can be wrong? All devices have same workgroup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean that the Windows computer can't see the Mac? You've written that your  "*windows computer cannot see [your] windows computer*", which doesn't seem to make sense in context.